# Is there a way to test if the co-variate distributions of two matrices (two sets) is same?

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning

Is there a way to test if the co-variate distributions of two matrices (two sets, for example, the training set and the test set)?

For example, the training set *Xtr* is a 200-by-10 matrix, and the test set *Xte* is a 20-by-10 matrix, what is a good way to test them if in the same distribution?

We know that if the test set is not located in the distribution of the training set, the model performance will be poor in the test step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start out testing whether the column means are similar. A sample size of 20 rows is not a very large sample, so any of these tests will have low power to detect differences. If the means-comparison passes that first hurdle to your satisfaction (and you should determine what level of confidence is needed in advance, possibly with simulation), then you could then move to comparing the variance-covariance matrices for the training and test sets. Statisticians call this comparing "moments". Means are the first moment and variance-covariance matrices would be comparing the second moments. This won't be a complete test since there are an infinitude of distributions with the same first two moments, but if you can assume some regularity (unimodal, "typical" parametric distributions) it will identify gross departures from "sameness".

Here's a bit of R code that could be expanded to examine the capacity of a statistic based on differences in column means to detect meaningful differences:

```
S <- numeric(2000); 
for( i in 1:2000 ) {
         Xtr <- matrix ( rnorm(2000) , 200, 10)
         Xte <- matrix ( rnorm(200) , 20, 10)
         S[i] <- sum( (colMeans(Xtr) -colMeans(Xte) )^2 )}
 quantile(S, c(0.05, 0.95) )
       5%       95% 
0.2139709 0.9903655
```

So if you did this test and only one test column differed from its corresponding train by one unit (which is the same as the standard deviation of these random variates)  you would have a 85% chance of picking up that difference with this constructed test:

```
 S2 <- numeric(2000); 
 for( i in 1:2000 ) { 
         Xtr <- matrix ( c(rnorm(1800), rnorm(200,1)) , 200, 10)
         Xte <- matrix ( rnorm(200) , 20, 10)
         S2[i] <- sum( (colMeans(Xtr) -colMeans(Xte) )^2 )}

> quantile(S2, seq(.05,.95,by=.05) )
       5%       10%       15%       20%       25%       30%       35% 
0.7804337 0.9126619 1.0002436 1.0787566 1.1487546 1.2313563 1.2865692 
      40%       45%       50%       55%       60%       65%       70% 
1.3533671 1.4127428 1.4837020 1.5567610 1.6277884 1.7024990 1.7727130 
      75%       80%       85%       90%       95% 
1.8496707 1.9439307 2.0588812 2.2175750 2.4848571
```

With 10 columns, you will have n*(n+1)/2 unique variances and covariance pairs to assemble in some sort of summary. Again you could do squares pairwise differences. Adding them produces a statistic seems likely to have a fair chance of having low power to detect individual differences, but you can again assess that potential by throwing in some heteroschedasticity and different theoretical distribution in your simulations that should be designed to draw upon your scientific domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps want to run a [Kolgomorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)? The relevant R function is [ks.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how such a test would be applied to the kinds of *multivariate* datasets described in the question?